# How to set ContentType inside an HttpEntity object?

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have the following Java code:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
ReadContent = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

I need that the entity's content is always read as an UTF-8 content type.

Unfortunately  EntityUtils.toString method use the second parameter only if the content type is not specified inside the HttpEntity object, instead I need to force to use always the utf-8 content-type.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't make much sense. If the response content was encoded with a character encoding X, decoding it with character encoding Y would cause undefined results.

> instead I need to force to use always the utf-8 content-type

I don't recommend this, but you can always get the response's `InputStream` and process the bytes as you see fit.

```
InputStream responseContent = entity.getContent();
```

(Don't forget to `close()` it.)

Comment: You're right, but I receive data from different sources and I have to fix bad coding issues.

Using getContent solved the problem. Thanks!